# Cannot invoke '==' with argument

Tags: ios, core-data, swift, migration

I changed my core data model by adding an attribute to an entity. I've done a lightweight migration, but when I run the app I get a nil for some for the added attribute and thus a crash. I simply want to check for a nil and exclude the attribute if it is nil so as to avoid the crash. I've tried to do this with an if statement, but I get the error in the title. How can I get around this?

```
if comments == nil {
        cell.textLabel!.text! = "\(totalWorkTimeInHours) hours"
        cell.detailTextLabel!.text! = "Date: \(dateString)"

    } else {

        cell.textLabel!.text! = "\(totalWorkTimeInHours) hours"
        cell.detailTextLabel!.text! = "Date: \(dateString)\nComments: \(comments)"

    }
```

"Comments" is a string from Core Data. I know the error has something to do with the fact that I can't compare a string with nil, but I'm not sure how else to do it.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Have you tried the `if let` syntax?

Comment: it still complains about trying to compare string with nil

Comment: Then perhaps your Core Data property is not an optional type? What type is the property--is it `String` or `String?` or `String!`? If it is the first one, then you really can't compare it to nil because Swift thinks it's required to have a value.

Comment: It was set to String I changed it to String! and I believe it's working how I want it to now. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

```
var comments: String? = nil
if let comments = comments {
    println(comments)
} else {
    println("empty")
}
```